# Angular Material Drag & Drop - Repeat main box image

Tags: angular, typescript

Implemented a function to select images and preview them in boxes.

Goal is to make them draggable in order to sort them.

My problem is that when selecting multiple images, it repeats the big box image in one of the small boxes, can you remove that?

The goal is to select 3 images and get the preview of the 3, then if you want to drag an image from the small boxes to the big box I change their positions.

**html**

```
<div class="drop">
      <div class="cont" *ngIf="urls.length === 0">
        <div class="browse" >
            Upload files
          </div>
        <div class="desc">
          Click to upload
        </div>       
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="urls.length > 0" cdkDropList  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
          <img [src]="urls[0]" cdkDrag>
        </div>
        <input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/*">
    </div>

    <div class="row" cdkDropList  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <div class="Upcard" *ngFor="let url of urls" cdkDrag>
          <img [src]="url">
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Component .ts**

```
files:any;
  urls = new Array<string>();
  detectFiles(event) {
    this.files = event.target.files;
    if (this.files.length < 7) {

      for (let file of this.files) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          this.urls.push(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    }
  }

 drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.urls, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is to make a image in first place and setting the same div in the drop list:

html:

```
<div class="drop" *ngIf="urls.length === 0">
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="browse">
      Upload files
    </div>
    <div class="desc">
      Click to upload
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/*">
</div>


<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
  <div *ngFor="let url of urls; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="i === 0" class="drop">
      <img [src]="url" cdkDrag>
      <input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/*">
    </div>
    <div class="Upcard" *ngIf="i !== 0">
      <img [src]="url">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ts:

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
  moveItemInArray(this.urls, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-seeq6x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: It didn't work that way, it still gives the white spacing and so you can't swap the big box image with the small one :( You can access my stackblitz pls link

Comment: The only problem now is that it doesn't swap the image with the big box.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmdm5p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html see if this works for you.

Comment: He swaps the image of the small boxes with the big one, but not always, I don't know why

Comment: Very strange then, I select 3 images, I can easily switch positions between the small boxes, but if you want to swap with the big one, nothing happens :(

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-seeq6x I sent the link incorrectly, try this.

Comment: Just found out a solution that makes the code cleaner, check it out on answer stackblitz, you can even drag the big image that way :)

Answer (score 0):

so, every time you try to drop an image into the big box or the first small box, the image will be set to the big box.
To handle that you need to create an index to *urls* in the **Html** side and using **ngIf** directive to check if the index is not equal 0.

like that

```
<div class="drop">
  <div class="cont" *ngIf="urls.length === 0">
    <div class="browse" >
        Upload files
      </div>
    <div class="desc">
      Click to upload
    </div>       
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="urls.length > 0" cdkDropList  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <img [src]="urls[0]" cdkDrag>
    </div>
    <input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/*">
</div>

<div class="row" cdkDropList  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
<div *ngFor="let url of urls; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="i !== 0" class="Upcard" cdkDrag>
  <img [src]="url">
</div>
```

Comment: you need to check the entire box, not just the image (to remove the white box).

Comment: You're right, he's leaving the box space, just doesn't display the image. The problem with this solution is that it creates a new box with the same image as the big box, same problem as described in the post image. If you know how to solve this I would appreciate it

Comment: I edited my solution to attend this issue, you need to ngIf the div before the image, like @SafwanMh proposed